# Unhandled rejection Error When Building Vue.js Project

Tags: vue.js

When running `npm run build` on my Vue project, I receive the following error:

`Unhandled rejection Error: original.line and original.column are not numbers -- you probably meant to omit the original mapping entirely and only map the generated position. If so, pass null for the original mapping instead of an object with empty or null values.`

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Comment: Is `original` a variable you're using or is it being used in a package you're using?

Comment: I just experienced same thing and and not sure it's is not related to any variable.. i have not found a fix.

Comment: I am getting the same thing. This is a project straight from Vue CLI. I haven't changed a single line of code or setting.

Comment: @DelenaMalan, I am not sure.  It's just a simple 1 pager that I created using the base project from Vue CLI, so I have not changed anything other than the App.Vue file and HelloWorld component.

Comment: @LeftOnTheMoon, exactly!  It's like an issue straight out of the box.

Comment: Might be related to [this issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/4210). Perhaps add comment to the issue to say that you're having a similar issue.

Answer (score 5):

Install for your project and run build again

```
npm i terser@4.0.0
npm run build
```

Comment: Seems like something is corrupted in the latest terser 4.0.1 which was released 15 hours ago. https://github.com/terser-js/terser/commits/master

Comment: Yep! Setting my project to specifically get terser@4.0.0 fixed the problem and I can build sourcemaps again. Hopefully a fix will be out soon.

Answer (score 4):

If you have `vue.config.js`, setting `productionSourceMap: false` resolves the issue when running `npm run build` on a vuejs project.

https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#productionsourcemap

```
module.exports = {
    // other config
    productionSourceMap: false
}
```

If using webpack(not tested), then `sourceMap: null`

https://github.com/webpack/webpack-sources/issues/28#issuecomment-342066023

Then re-run build (might need to also delete `package-lock.json` or `node_modules`)

```sh
npm run build
```